# AWS S3: Need to send a notification if we get an object greater than 10 MB in our S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Is there any way to notify people through email whenever we upload an object/objects of size greater than 10 MBs in our S3 bucket?

Comment: Is there any particular reason for wanting to do this (eg to reduce storage costs)? There might be another way to achieve your actual end-goal? Feel free to edit your question to add more details.

Comment: Yes John, its came as a part of business need. Yes, may be cost can be a factor.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein actually we can't attach more than 10MBs file in amazon email. so we need to notify user than the attachment is too big for sending the email notification.

Comment: How are the users uploading the files? If it is being done via a pre-signed URL, I think you can include a size-limit in the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way.
You can have Lambda triggered for PutObject and Multipart upload operation (if used) on S3 bucket.

[Configuring Amazon S3 Event Notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html)

The big deal here is to write lambda(email portion) and find the object name/properties which was upload, read metadata or size and then decide whether to send email or not.

Comment: I'm still tryign to figure out a way through lambda , of getting the alarm and size of object whenever an object gets uploaded. + I am not too good in writing labda scripts, so if someone can help out with this. I will be really thankful to them